# Async.forEach call the callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

How to call the foreach callback after complete the series?

My code:

```
async.forEach(rowsIni, function (row, callback2) {
    strQuery = "SELECT ...";
    DB.query(strQuery, row, function (err, rows) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("SQL Error(SELECT) > " + err.message);
        } else {
        async.series([
            function (callback) {
                async.parallel([
                    function (callback) {
                        callback();
                    },
                    function (callback) {
                        callback();
                    }
                 ], function (err) {
                     callback();
                 });
            },
            function (callback) {
                callback();
            }
        ], function() {
            callback2
        });
        }
    });
}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("ASYNC Error > " + err.message);
    }
    console.log('END OF FOREACH');
    callback(otherFunction);
});
```

How to call the callback2? If I call thus, the callback2 is not called.

Comment: the indentation is rather confusing.

Comment: looks like you have a syntax error.. `async.paralell([function () {},function () {});` missing `]`? code is all over the place.

Comment: @KevinB now it's correct

Comment: it should be getting called, assuming there's no error stopping it all.

Comment: I did debug, and it comes to the callback 2, but does not execute the code:
`function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("ASYNC Error > " + err.message);
    }
    console.log('END OF FOREACH');
    callback(otherFunction);
}`

Comment: Is async.foreach what you think it is? I think you want async.each or async.eachSeries

Comment: @T.B. I just need to call another function when the foreach is completed

Comment: If you want the rows to process in parallel, use async.each. If you want them to process in series, use async.eachSeries.

Comment: I have solved the problem. There was one callback into IF in async.parallel and depending on the result it does not perform the callback.

Answer (score 0):

```
async.series([...], function() {
    callback2 // does nothing
})
```

You don't actually call `callback2`. Either use `callback2()` (call it) or

```
async.series([...], callback2);
```

To just pass the callback function.

edit:

```
async.eachSeries(rowsIni, function (row, callback2) {
    ...
    async.series([
        function (callback) {
            async.parallel([
                ... functions
            ], callback);
        },
        function (callback) {
            callback();
        }
    ], callback2);
});
```

Comment: If I use this form:
`async.series([...], callback2);`

The callback is called before the series is completed

Comment: Then one of the async series functions isn't working. Check that your async.parallel is correct. It should also be `async.parallel([...], callback)`

Comment: Still does not work.
The code below does not cause interference?
`DB.query(strQuery, row, function (err, rows) {`

Comment: Check my answer again for the edit with the code block, it should work that way. I don't think DB.query will affect it. In your newest post you call callback2 in the wrong place - make sure it's the 2nd parameter when calling async.series

Comment: I have solved the problem. There was one callback into IF in async.parallel and depending on the result it does not perform the callback.